# Printing a cycle in a Graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I'd like to find any cycle inside a graph and print a list that represent the first cycle I find.

Here's my work so far:

```
def find_cycle(self):
    def aux(vertex, visited, parent, path):
        visited.add(vertex)
        neigh = self.neighbors_out(vertex)
        for n in neigh:
            if n not in visited:
                if aux(n, visited, parent, path):
                    path.append(n)
                    return True
            elif parent != n:
                path.append(n)
                return True
        return False

    vertices = self.vertices()
    visited = set()
    cycle = []
    while vertices:
        vertex = vertices.pop()
        if aux(vertex, visited, -1, cycle):
            return cycle
        vertices = vertices - visited

    return None
```

I tried to use the DFS approach and update the path, return it if it is a cycle.
It doesn't work extremely well, any idea to improve it ?

Comment: What does "does not work extremely well" mean?

Comment: It means that I wrote some assert() statements to check whether my code works or not, and it does find a cycle on some examples, not on some others.

Comment: I already checked if the asserts are correct and they are, and I was unable to use these unit tests to understand why is my code not working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do Breadth first search, not depth first search. you pick a root vertex, and in each vertex you visit, you store the path from the root to that vertex (easy to do recursively). When you finally see a vertex you have seen before, you concatenate its path with the path you have, and there is your cycle.